# ZuulException: Forwarding error in Spring cloud running locally

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I get this very common zuul error, when running spring cloud microservices locally.

If I specify microservice address in application.yml it works fine, so I am wondering why it doesn't discovery the service address properly without explicitly specifying it, especially that this is a new behaviour.

```
 zuul:
   routes:
     my-service:
     path: /myservice/**
     #url: http://localhost:8081
```

Any hints what could have caused this?

Here is some part of stacktrace.

```
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:57)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463)
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClien t.java:112)
... 137 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using service discovery if you aren't using `url`, like eureka or consul?

Comment: Yes, I am using consul. Actually this configuration is doing its job. cloud.spring.consul.discovery.hostname=localhost but I would expect to work this as default. I am quit sure it is a windows hosts configuration or firewall, but couldn't figure out what is the problem.